# Javascript + PHP, always downloading the same

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with downloading my files from the website.

When i load my page, i cant download the file and its the correct one. (http://example.com/file.php?id=111) but when i refresh the youtube embed, it shows my next video (works with mysql) and when i click again on the download button it still downloads the previous file. And not the next file.

**Code Snipets:**

**BLANK.PHP** (is the page where my player is)

```
<script>
function ajax_request(){
    $("#video_frame").load("<?php echo $actual_link; ?>");
}
</script>
<?php $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>   
<div id="video_frame" class="video">
    <?php include('video.php'); ?>
</div>
```

**VIDEO.PHP**

```
<script>
$('#download_ajax').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
     window.open('http://example.com/fetch/?videofile=http://www.example.com/watch?v=<?php echo $urlid; ?>','_blank');
});
</script>
<?php
//MYSQL CONNECTION
    if($_GET['p'] == 'house') {
        $hitsq = $mysqli->query("SELECT urlid FROM `***` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
        $hits = $hitsq->fetch_assoc();
        $urlid = $hits['urlid'];
    } else if ($_GET['p'] == 'drumandbass') {
        $hitsq = $mysqli->query("SELECT urlid FROM `***` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6");
        $hits = $hitsq->fetch_assoc();
        $urlid = $hits['urlid'];
    } else if ($_GET['p'] == 'hiphop') {
        $hitsq = $mysqli->query("SELECT urlid FROM `***` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6");
        $hits = $hitsq->fetch_assoc();
        $urlid = $hits['urlid'];
    } else if ($_GET['p'] == 'futurehouse') {
        $hitsq = $mysqli->query("SELECT urlid FROM `****` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6");
        $hits = $hitsq->fetch_assoc();
        $urlid = $hits['urlid'];
    } else if ($_GET['p'] == 'rock') {
        $hitsq = $mysqli->query("SELECT urlid FROM `****` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,6");
        $hits = $hitsq->fetch_assoc();
        $urlid = $hits['urlid'];
    }
?>    
<div class="video">
    <iframe name="Right" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://example.com/embed/<?php echo $urlid ?>?rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
</iframe>
</div>
```

[Site Snippet Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0iFC.png)

Comment: A lot of this seems to imply we know how your application works. Maybe I read it too quickly, but it sounds confusing.

Comment: You would have to reload the page for the php output $url_id to change. There is no canvas in your snippet, I think the answer to your question  will involve explaining php outputs and page loads.

Comment: @jesse you got a better idea now?

Comment: Where is `$_GET['p']` defined? I do not see that in the URL.

Comment: @Twisty its defined as blank.php?p=

Comment: You may want to include that as part of your post, that when you call example.com/blank.php?p=house etc - What does the Source code look like the first time, when it fails?